# Correct way to use Notation

Tags: custom-notation

I have tried to create some Notation declarations as follows

```
<< Notation`
Notation[Subscript[x_, i_] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] x[i]]
Notation[OverBar[x_] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] mean[x]]
```

Mathematica9 throws the following errors for the declarations

> Notation::noexbtag: The external representation Subscript[x_, y_] does not have an embedded TemplateBox with tag NotationTemplateTag. The Notation statement Notation[Subscript[x_, y_][DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]x[y]] may not have been entered using the palette, or the embedded TemplateBox may have been deleted. The embedded TemplateBox ensures correct parsing and retention of proper styling and grouping information. >>

and

> Notation::noexbtag: The external representation Overscript[x_, *] does not have an embedded TemplateBox with tag NotationTemplateTag. The Notation statement Notation[Overscript[x*, _][DoubleLongLeftRightArrow]mean[x]] may not have been entered using the palette, or the embedded TemplateBox may have been deleted. The embedded TemplateBox ensures correct parsing and retention of proper styling and grouping information. >>

respectively.

It is not really clear to me what is going on. I read the documentation for `TemplateBox` and looked up `NotationTemplateTag` which seems to have been replaced by `ParsedBoxWrapper`. After following some related function I thought the following might be what is required:

```
Notation[ToBoxes[Subscript[x_, y_]]\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] x[y]]
Notation[ToBoxes[OverBar[x_]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] mean[x]]
```

or perhaps

```
Notation[MakeBoxes[Subscript[x_, y_]]\[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] x[y]]
Notation[MakeBoxes[OverBar[x_]] \[DoubleLongLeftRightArrow] mean[x]]
```

but both of those throw errors as well. So what is the right way to declare these notations? I am aware that setting up subscripts as a notation for function application is not something you would want to do in practice, but I am just experimenting.

Also do I actually need to import the Notation package or `Notation` buit-in with Mathematica9?

Comment: Works for me. Are you using the palette to enter the notation (you *must* IIRC)? Also, pattern s/b on both sides.

Comment: If you've not already, take a look at the section [Entering Notations](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Notation/tutorial/NotationSymbolizeAndInfixNotation.html) (toward the bottom). Use of `ParsedBoxWrapper` is covered there for using `Notation` constructs without the palette.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Notation[OverBar[x_] \[DoubleLongRightArrow] Mean[x_]]
z=Range[10];
OverBar[z]

(* 11/2 *)
```

n.b.: You *cannot* just copy/paste the above, per my comment.

Comment: Ok, that did work for me once I used the palette. One difference with what I tried before is that the second `x` in the Notation is also followed by an underscore in your code. What is the logic behind that?

Comment: @DanielMahler: Covered in the doc. section I linked in the comment above - I'm not a `Notation` expert by any means, but I'm pretty certain an error is thrown if patterns used are not on both sides. Perhaps one of the resident experts will illuminate this, or the referred docs. might clarify.